# Split table into 4 parts

Tags: tables

Could you please tell me how I can create this kind of tables in latex?

Thanks in advance,[image]

Comment: Do you mean that you want an overlap of tables?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Are you familiar with the `longtable` environment?

Comment: Also, I see three part, not four. ;)

Comment: I tried to use **longtable** but it gives me a long table split over pages. The code I used was mentioned in (https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Tables)

Comment: @IhabSami Hence, do you want the table parts to overlap? Please insert your [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) in your post, [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192).

Comment: @giusva, no, I have a long dataset (3044x2) and I want to divide this dataset into 4 tables with an overlap like the posted image.

Comment: @CarLaTeX, Sorrry I did not get your point.

Comment: @Mico I tried to use `longtable` but it gives me a long table split over pages. The code I used was mentioned in  (https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Tables)

Comment: @Ihab Sorry but I still don't get what you need. You wrote that you don't want an overlap of tables but you want to divide your dataset into 4 tables that overlap. Please be more clear.

Comment: @giusva Sorry for my bad English. I just need to have a table like the one I mentioned in the post. Just tell me which package I can use and I will try. I hope now it is clear :-)

Comment: @Ihab With `longtable` you can have a table that can split across several pages. The image in the link you provided isn't the result you obtain with `longtable`. If you want to overlap tables you could use TiKz or, maybe, you could try with negative `\hspace` and `\vspace` using normal tables.

Comment: @giusva Thank, I will try it and let you know :-)

Comment: @Ihab Give it a try and let we know your results with the code you'll produce. It will be a good starting point for further improvements.

Comment: @giusva I have solved it, but I do not know how to share the code. I am not familiar with this site.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\begin{table}
\caption{Data example}
\label{TAB:label}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Frame No. $1$}\\
\hline
Index  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{range data}\\
\hline\hline
0   &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3.11}\\
1   &  3.11\\
2   &  3.00 \\
\vdots  & \vdots \\
100 &  2.26 \\
101 &  2.28 \\
\vdots  & \vdots \\
757 &  1.51\\
758 &   4.05 \\
759 &   4.08 \\
760 &   4.08 \\
\end{tabular}
\hspace{-0.4in}\raisebox{-0.5in}{
\small\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{13pt}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Frame No. $2$}\\
\hline
0   &  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{3.11}\\
1   & 3.11\\
2   &  3.11 \\
\vdots  & \vdots \\
100 &  2.26 \\
101 &  2.28 \\
\vdots  & \vdots \\
757 &  1.51\\
758 &   4.05 \\
759 &   4.08 \\
760 &   4.08 \\
\end{tabular}
}
\hspace{-0.4in}\raisebox{-0.95in}{
\small\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{13pt}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Frame No. $3$}\\
\hline
0   &  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{3.11}\\
1   &  3.11\\
2   &  3.11 \\
\vdots  & \vdots \\
100 &  2.26 \\
101 &  2.28 \\
\vdots  & \vdots \\
757 &  1.51\\
758 &   4.05 \\
759 &   4.08 \\
760 &   4.08 \\
\end{tabular}}
\hspace{-0.35in}\raisebox{-1.4in}{
\small\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{13pt}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Frame No. $4$}\\
\hline
0   &  3.11\\
1   &  3.11\\
2   &  3.10 \\
\vdots   & \vdots \\
100 &  2.26 \\
101 &  2.28 \\
\vdots  & \vdots \\
757 &  1.51\\
758 &   4.05 \\
759 &   4.08 \\
760 &   4.08 \\
\hline\hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
```